# Add folder to search exclude Glob patterns in workspace, and inherit Glob patterns from user settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to add a Glob pattern to `"search.exclude"` in the `settings.json` of a workspace, and inherit all other Glob patterns I have defined in my user settings?

That is, I do not want to have to list in the local workspace `settings.json` all those Glob patterns I already defined in my user `settings.json` file. I just want to add a new Glob pattern.

So, I am looking for the equivalent of:

```
PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

which adds a new location to `PATH`, appended to whatever was there before.